# UAC Status from Command Line

Tags: command-line, security, uac

Is there any command which will tell me the state of UAC?  Eg it's switched on, off of which level it's on.

Comment: From user [Justin D](https://superuser.com/users/952424/justin-d): Please note that the computer needs to be rebooted after registry value is set for UAC disable/enable to be effective. Reg query may show UAC is disabled/enabled but it may not be effective if the computer is not rebooted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run from the command prompt

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA
```

if you get

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

UAC is enabled, but if you get

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

UAC is disabled.

Comment: Great thanks!  As that's in HKLM I guess only an admin user could run that though?

Comment: @AdemDempsey I'm not sure, you'd have to check... I don't currently use any non-admin users.

Comment: @AdemDempsey I checked by creating a non-admin user and it works fine!

Comment: @BloodPhilia - In some edge cases this does not work. On my system `EnableLUA` is set to 0x1 yet still UAC is not active. This can happen on a server OS where you have removed the GUI components. UAC is never enabled on Server Core.

Comment: Perfect! We had hkey mis-spelled in our documentation and this made the command work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for Windows 7 - Windows 10 as a batch file (`.cmd` or `.bat`) or command line.

**Batch file:**

```
    @echo off

    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" | find  "0x0" >NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"  ECHO UAC disabled
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1"  ECHO UAC enabled
    pause

    exit
```

**Command Line:**

```
    REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
```

If you get "0x0" UAC is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA ^| find /i "enablelua"') do (if "%%~a"=="0x1" (echo Enabled) else (echo Disabled))
```